# A question on Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function and that $f(-1)=f(1)=0$. Show that there is $c\in(-1,1)$ such that $$f(c)=\frac{c}{1-c^2}$$

I am not sure if this is a new question as I set it this morning, after solved a similar question. I wanted to prove it using the same idea (Intermediate Value Theorem) but it was not that nice...

Can anyone help me on this?

By the way, the 'similar question' I mentioned above is as follow:

> Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function and that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=2$. Show that there is $c\in(0,1)$ such that $$f(c)=\frac{1}{c}$$
>   The hint given was to let $g(x)=xf(x)$ and use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: I guess that $c\in (-1,1)$.

Comment: Have you tried using a similar sort of hint?  Like using the intermediate value theorem on some function $g(x)$ which you define (somehow)?

Comment: @Sigur, thanks for pointing it. I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Let $g(x)=[f(x) (1-x^2)]-x$. Then $g(-1)=1$ and $g(1)=-1$.

Comment: This is nice! It help me to generalize all other possible similar questions!

Answer (score 2):

If $f(0) = 0$ then we are done with $c=0$.  Otherwise $f(0) >0$ or $f(0) <0$.  Suppose the former.  Define $g(x) = \frac{(1-x^2)f(x)}{x}$.  Then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = \infty$ so by IVT there is $c$ with $g(c) = 1$.  Suppose the latter.  Then $\lim_{x \to 0^-} g(x) = \infty$ so by IVT there is $c$ with $g(c) = 1$.